# git init under python script called by git filter-branch uses wrong directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, version-control, git-filter-branch

I run the following MWE of python script to read throw commits and create another git projec somewhere else.

I call this script this way to iterate through git projectA and create another git projectB under bash command of

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "python3 /media/sf_git/register-commits.py /home/mercury/splitted" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

The argument to `python3` is the script that runs on each commit and the path after it is the location where project B is supposed to be created.

/media/sf_git/register-commits.py

```
import os
import sys


def git_init(module):
    os.system('git init ' + module)

def create_project(parent, module):
    os.chdir(parent)
    print('parent:', parent)
    git_init(module)
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(parent, module, '.git')):
        sys.exit('.git folder is not created.')


arg1 =  sys.argv[1]
if arg1 is None:
    sys.exit('The script argument is not provided')


commit_id = os.environ["GIT_COMMIT"]

module = 'projectB'
cwd = os.getcwd()

try:
    dst_module_path = os.path.join(arg1, module)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_module_path):
        create_project(arg1, module)
except Exception as e:
    print('Error: ' + str(e))
finally:
    os.chdir(cwd)
```

The problem is that the `os.chdir` can change the path. I have even printed it. That's correct. But the git init command runs in the same working directory of project A instead of project B. It gives me the following error

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
     set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
Proceeding with filter-branch...

Rewrite 8a30d5630ab7ead31ecc3b30122054d27eec0dbe (1/3058) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/mercury/projectA/.git/
.git folder is not created.
parent: /home/mercury/splitted
tree filter failed: python3 /media/sf_git/register-commits.py /home/mercury/splitted
```

It creates an empty folder `projectB` under `/home/mercury/splitted` with no `.git` folder inside it.

It looks like that there is another side problem that the projectA is changed. Because when I run the script for the second time, there is an error

```
Proceeding with filter-branch...

You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

It looks like the projectA is hurt. The only way to fix that I know is to copy `.git` folder of projectA from the backup.

Using `subprocess.Popen` gives me a similar result:

```
def git_init(module):
    parent = os.getcwd()
    print('parent:', parent)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'init', module], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=parent)
    p_status = proc.wait()
    (output, err) = proc.communicate()
    print(output)
```

output

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
     set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
Proceeding with filter-branch...

Rewrite 8a30d5630ab7ead31ecc3b30122054d27eec0dbe (1/3058) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
parent: /home/mercury/splitted
parent: /home/mercury/splitted
b'Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/mercury/projectA/.git/\n'
.git folder is not created.
tree filter failed: python3 /media/sf_git/register-commits.py /home/mercury/splitted
```

This is strange that git creates a folder inside `/home/mercury/splitted` but tries initiating the `.git` under `/home/mercury/projectA`.

When I run the scripts under normal python environment, everything is fine. But under `git filter-branch` here the paths do not apply to `git` even though the working directory is changed fine. In addition to that, it looks like projectA gets corrupted when `git init` is applied for another directory.

I am not sure exactly if this is a `git` problem or `python` problem.

What is wrong and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is wrong ...

There are two things you must not do in a tree filter, in `git filter-branch`, in general:

1. change the working directory;
2. use Git commands.

This is not necessarily an *exclusive* list, and, luckily, there are some ways around these two.

> and how to fix this problem?

The limitation on changing directories is actually specific to *shell commands run in the top level shell* (filter-branch `eval`s your filter here).  Since you're firing up a completely separate process, `python`, that allows you to change the working directory.  But it's worth mentioning the issue, since an attempt to *optimize* your filter might result in running into it.

The limitation on using Git commands is because a tree filter is specifically aimed at letting you use *non*-Git commands to *rework the contents* of each commit.  Using `git filter-branch` simply to *examine* the contents of each commit wasn't the intent here.

Fortunately, there is a simple workaround for running `git init` like this: you just need to *remove* the environment variable `GIT_DIR` from the environment when you invoke Git.  If you invoke other Git commands there may be more environment variables you must unset.

Overall, though, it's not clear why you're trying to use `git filter-branch` for this.  If you want to get a list of commits, the correct tool is usually `git rev-list`.  If you want to get files *from* those commits, things get more complex, but filter-branch is still probably not the right tool.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. You helped me to find a different workaround. This is just a MWE. I have a SVN with a bad designed converted to git. It has a lot of projects under the same folder. There are many branches that repeat all of those folders too. What I want to do is to separate all those project under the correct branch. The problem is that these projects has structural changes and renaming in the middle of commits too. It is very complicated to handle them and put them under different project repos with the right branch. Your explanations is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. If you are working with some existing repositories in some other VCS and want to drop commits into Git, the Git-side tool-of-choice is usually `git fast-import`. It's designed to read streams of data from exporters; such exporters are often written in Python. It's a bit klunky to use, but will probably be the way you want to go.